# Way to get desktop to act like a library?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, libraries

I'm on windows 7; how can I make my desktop act (basically) like a library? (Libraries being the [new Windows 7 feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861346.aspx))

Comment: Want to clarify your question a bit? I guess you don't want to borrow books from your desktop?

Comment: In windows 7, "Libraries" offer what amounts to a union view of multiple folders. I think he wants the icons on his desktop to come from multiple folders, possibly with some sort of divider between them.

Comment: What Darth Android said :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open libraries.

Right click->New->Library.

Give it a name (e.g. desktop)

Open your new library and add the desktop folder to it.

Is that the sort of thing you're aiming for?

Comment: I think he wants the files in the Desktop library to appear on his desktop.

Comment: Create a symlink from Desktop folder to the Desktop Library? @Phoshi

Comment: @Sathya: but are libraries even real folders for the purposes of symlinking?

Comment: Valid point, @RCIX forgot libraries cannot be symlinked, however they can be drag-and-dropped onto the desktop http://i.imgur.com/J9yMH.jpg